# grails 2.5.1 ignores Spock functional tests

Tags: grails, testing, spock, grails-2.5

I just migrated an application from grails 2.2.4 to grails 2.5.1. Now spock tests are not executed. The test directory looks as following:

```
test
   - unit
      - FirstSpec
      - SecondSpec
      - ... (more Spock tests)  
   - functional
      - FirstTests
      - FirstSpec
      - ... (more JUnit & Spock tests)
```

Following behavior occurs:

```
grails test-app unit:spock
```

> does not run any test

```
grails test-app unit:
```

> runs all spock unit tests

```
grails test-app functional:spock
```

> does not run any tests

```
grails test-app functional:
```

> runs only JUnit functional tests

With grails 2.2.4 all test have been executed. I followed the migration guide provided at the grails homepage (removing spock-plugin etc.)
Does anyone have an idea what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. This plugin adds support for functional spock tests: https://grails.org/plugin/functional-spock

I don't know why this functionality is not provided by default.

Regards,Rumpel